# How to throw eclipse plugin jar into eclipse plugins directory and start running in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

As you know that we can place or throw a plugin jar file inside plugins or dropins directory of eclipse installation. Once we restart the eclipse, the plugin jar gets loaded and it starts working. I want to achieve exactly this feature in my eclipse rcp plugin development without using complicated p2 provisioning system.

Briefly, I have an Eclipe RCP application just like mail template, other developer will create **a.jar, b.jar and c.jar** as **eclipse plugins**. I will put the jar/s files inside eclipse plugins and manually restart the eclipse so that I can see the newly loaded plugins ui.

Please help me how to do it. Eclipse does it. If it is not possible, is it possible to load a plugin jar from a particular path from local system programmatically ? Please suggest.

Comment: Instead of p2 you can use the `org.eclipse.update.configurator` with a [`config.ini` like this one](https://sourceforge.net/p/pacx/code/HEAD/tree/net.sf.pacx/configuration/config.ini): via start levels first start Equinox (OSGi), then the `org.eclipse.update.configurator` which scans the `plugins` directory (the `dropins` directory is p2 related) and finally the Eclipse runtime. Alternatively, you can configure p2 to scan certain directories on every start.

Comment: Sir,  howlger, you are great , it is working as expected. Now how to add theese two lines  "osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@start
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4" so that while building using tycho, it will be visible in my app.ini for app.exe ? I need this small help Sir.

Comment: In your `.product` file in the tab _Configuration_ you have to choose _"Use an existing config.ini file"_.

Comment: Sir, I found small issue, while placing the jar file, everything is working, but after removing, I can also see some old UI and images have been removed. I even did app.exe -clean. Any suggestion Sir ?

Comment: The UI will persisted in the workspace in `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi`. As far as I know, there are no options to remove the UI elements that no longer exist on startup. I guess you have to write your own code for that.

Comment: Hello, I have the same isue, but this don't work for me.

I'm using Eclipse 4.23:
and I have this in folder plugins

AgroTracker_1.1.176.202403110000.jar
and file AgroTracker_1.1.176.202403112200.jar

My intention is that Eclipse only get the last one: AgroTracker_1.1.176.202403112200.jar.
And eventualy with a new file, use the last one.
Thanks, best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from howlger Sir.

Add the below two lines in your applicationconfig.ini ie, if your app name is abc, then you will have abc.exe and next to exe file you will find abc.ini. In this .ini file, you can add below two lines. To generate a config file, you can use product configuration tab and below, you will find Propeties, you can add list of properties like this. He in this case key will be "osgi.bundles" and value will be "org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@start". Also as suggested by howlger, you can add your custom config.ini file in the upper portion of configuration tab of product configuration.

**osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start,org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start,org.eclipse.core.runtime@start
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4**

Thanks a lot Sir, @howlger (https://stackoverflow.com/users/6505250/howlger).

Comment: Hi, I'm trying this solution without success in Eclipse Rcp 4.23.
What I have is an RCP App, and in the folder "plugins" i have: AgroTracker_1.1.176.202403120010,jar,  then in Eclipse I export only the plugin again, and it gives me: AgroTracker_1.1.176.202403121515.jar.
What I expect is that the app load last one, is that how it works ?